# Is it possible for spotbugs to skip kotlin files from pure maven configuration?

Tags: maven, kotlin, findbugs, spotbugs

I'm able to exclude `*.kt` files using

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludeFilterFile>spotbugs-exclude-filter.xml</excludeFilterFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and in `spotbugs-exclude-filter.xml` containing:

```
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Source name="~.*\.kt"/>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

However, with spotbugs being in a parent pom (used by both Java and Kotlin projects) I'd prefer a pure maven solution so inheriting projects don't need that additional xml file. Is it possible?

Comment: Based on the documentation you can create a separate artifact which contains the configuration. this can be either within your multi module build or a complete separate artifact see https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html

Answer (score 1):

SpotBugs makes the assumption that the code was compiled from Java classes (even though the class file is likely to have the correct filename).
If you look at the SpotBugs XML report file, you will see the source files according to SpotBugs. In order to exclude Kotlin classes you will have to do something like below because Kotlin compiled to `XxxxxxKt.class`

```
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Source name="~.*Kt\.java"/>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

Comment: This appears to not work any more in 2022 (Spotbugs 4.7.2). Instead the filter should be `"~.*\.kt"`

Answer (score 0):

In configuration of plugin use `includeFilterFile` instead `excludeFilterFile`.

And change pattern from `"~.*\.kt"` to `"~.*Kt\.java"`.